# AWS ECS Container environment variable terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, task, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to deploy  docker containers to ECS cluster of ec2 launch type. I want to set some of the cluster environment variable with reference to the host it is running. Eg: node_id = ip_addr/instance_id of ec2 instance it is running

Is there a way I can achieve this in terraform code? (dynamically get the host attributes to container env variables)

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do this from TF. But from container you can get a lot of [metadata info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html). It should contain info about instance.